# App component doesn't render child component

Tags: angular

My app.component is not rendering child component template but after inspecting on the webpage I can see customer-form.component but it's not rendering. I have added my files for all the components.

app.component.html=

```
<h1>Customer services</h1> <app-customer-form></app-customer-form>
```

app.module.ts=

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CustomDirectDirective } from './custom-direct.directive';
import { CustomerFormComponent } from './customer-form/customer-form.component';
import { DisplayCustomerComponent } from './display-customer/display-customer.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CustomDirectDirective,
    CustomerFormComponent,
    DisplayCustomerComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

customer-form.component.html=

```
<h2>this is customer form</h2>
```

customer-form.component.ts=

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Customer } from '../customer';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customer-form',
  templateUrl: './customer-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer-form.component.css']
})
export class CustomerFormComponent implements OnInit {
  

  constructor(public customer: Customer) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }


  customerForm(data: any){
    
  }

}
```

It shows child component while inspecting but doesn't render on page.

[image]

Comment: Assuming Customer is a correct injectable like a service I can't reproduce from code posted. [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-74277180-child?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Answer (score 0):

Make the child fit the container using CSS. i think the child height and width are 0*0

Comment: yeah it shows 0*0 after hovering on it, what changes should I make. Thanks

Comment: make the parent component fit the screen and make the child fit the parent component.
just  have to use basic css

Answer (score 0):

**It seems like a styling issue.**

- Make sure your template URL must match your Html file path.

If you still facing issues. Then you have to add your project to any live resource then we can help you.

Comment: My path is correct. It shows 0*0 when I hover on <app-customer-form> in inspect element